# How to load a JSP into another JSP coming from Struts 2 action

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, struts2, struts2-jquery

I need to load a JSP. The control is coming from an action into a JSP. The action is called  using jQuery post. The JSP page is not getting displayed but the execute method of action does get executed.

Can anyone tell me why?

```js
function ftpFetch() {
        $('#connectForm').submit(function() {
        $.post('<s:url action="ftpFetchAction" />', {
            userName : $('#name').val(),
            domainName : $('#domain').val(),
            password : $('#password').val(),
        }, function(data) {
        $("#connectdiv").hide();
        $("#result").html(data);
        }, "html");
    });
}
```

in `struts.xml`:

```
<action name="ftpFetchAction" class="com.olive.rm.controlPanel.ftp.FtpProgram" >
   <result name="success">/FtpFetch.jsp</result>
   <result name="error">/invaliddir.jsp</result>
</action>
```

action got executed.

Comment: Please show some code if possible.

Comment: how this could be answered without some extraction,give us some detailed info

Comment: hi thanks for your reply i am using jquery post method  and calling the action in struts2 the jsp page which should as a result from action shoul load in the same page

Comment: i gave the code above now please check it

Comment: add `alert(data);` after `function(data) {` and tell us if data is arriving. If yes, add JSP code, if not, add Action code.

Comment: What's in the response? Is the success callback being hit? Do you have a #result div?

Answer (score 0):

Look at this function it will work, I've corrected syntax errors, it looks like

```
function ftpFetch() {
  $('#connectForm').submit(function() {
    $.post('<s:url action="ftpFetchAction" />', {
      userName : $('#name').val(),
      domainName : $('#domain').val(),
      password : $('#password').val()
    }, function(data) {
      $("#connectdiv").hide();
      $("#result").html(data);
    });
  });
}
```

make sure you call it when document is in the ready state, so it could be successfully bound. It also be useful if the request has not a `decorator` attribute and cash-control headers turned off. JSP should contain fragments rendered to successful callback.